# SQLAlchemy in Flask - How to auto update the same column in another table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make sure that given two tables with many to many relationship, they are not only linked by the id but by another column too: the "name" column in user is referring to the "author" column in the post table.
I attempted various solutions including:

```
user_post = db.Table('user_post',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True),
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(95), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(180), unique=True , nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', secondary=user_post, backref='user')
    posts1 = db.relationship('Post', backref='post1', lazy='dynamic',
                        primaryjoin="user.name == post.author")


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User: {self.name}, {self.email}"


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column('author', db.String(95), db.ForeignKey('user.name'))
    # author = db.Column('author', db.String(95))
    title = db.Column(db.String(300))
    content = db.Column(db.Text(700))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(200))
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_post, backref='post')


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Title: {self.title}"
```

to test that if I change the name of a user, the author's name should change as well, I wrote as below:

```
user3.name = "Someone New"
db.session.commit()
print(post3.author)
```

and this is when I got the error:

**SQLAlchemy in Flask - AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'author'**

I tried to use the code by ensuring that the author is updated in different ways but I wanted the author to be updated automatically through ORM.
I checked the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html) and it is mentioned that there are exceptions to the referenced columns almost always define the primary key, but among the [cases](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html) I have seen, it was always referencing primary keys. [image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    author = db.Column(db.String(95), db.ForeignKey(User.name))
```

Comment: So by referring to the class as defined instead of the table name ? It gives the error 
 "sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'post.author' could not find table 'User' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'name' ". I wonder if it's because I already defined  tablename = 'user'

Comment: Sorry mate, please check the updated answer, my bad I made a small error

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understood what has been changed because the error stays the same if we use User instead of user, in which case there is no error but the code doesn't work as I intend it to (automatically updating author when user.name is updated)